# null values in optional columns

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Suppose I have a Table1, with three Columns: ID (Primary Key, Identity), A, and B

Now, suppose I have 3 methods, assuming they share nothing in common column-wise:

Method 1: C, D, E

Method 2: F, G, H, I

Method 3: J

I could make one table:
ID, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, M

Where M, is the name of the Method (or a Method ID).

However, if 90% of the time Method 3 is used, there would be many null values.
Is this a problem?  If so, is there a better way to set this up?

If I make each method its own table entity, how do I ensure each ID has exactly one method matching for it?

If I keep it as one table, how do I ensure ONLY C, D, E are filled in and F thru J are NULL if M is 1?

---

OK, seems some people had difficultly thinking abstractly, so I'll create a random concrete example applying the above:

Suppose I had records of people performing exercises.
Each record would always have an ID (to uniquely identify the event), a TIME_STARTED, and TIME_ENDED.

However, depending on which exercise they did, there would be different attributes needed.  Suppose there were only three exercises:

Elliptical: INCLINE, LEVEL, SPEED

Crunches: User_Weight, Reps, Delay, Extra_Weight

Dead Lift: Weight_Lifted

For each ID there could be only one "method".  Applying this, see above questions.

Comment: What do you mean by methods? where do c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,m come from if your table has only ID, A, B?

Comment: You may be asking the wrong question here. It may be better to start with "I need to store X data, what is the optimal schema?" As it stands it's difficult to help since we have no context, have no idea what ABCDEFGHIJM are, but it sounds like you're going in a very wrong direction.

Comment: Suppose, I record a test run, ID, A, and B are always part of every run.  However, if the run was done with method 1, I would need to store values in columns C, D, and E.  Which may be different data types than if method 2 was run needing columns F, G, H, I, etc.

Comment: @M_M it was meant to be generic on purpose, I figured it's a basic thing.  Sorry if you felt it was too abstract.

Comment: Abstract and vague are not the same thing. Either way, the big question is, what do you want to do with the data after you store it?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The question was extremely specific.  The accepted answer is what I was looking for.  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a [supertype/subtype](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505839.aspx) situation here. In this case, Table1 holds your supertype, and you would want to create a different table to hold each of your subtypes. The PK on these subtype tables would also be an FK to the supertype table. So you would have something like this:

```
Supertype_table
|    ID(PK)   |  A  |  B  |

Subtype1_table
|  ID(PK&FK)  |  C  |  D  |  E  |

Subtype2_table
|  ID(PK&FK)  |  F  |  G  |  H  |  I  |

Subtype3_table
|  ID(PK&FK)  |  J  |
```

The point of this schema is to make sure that you don't have a bunch of rows which are mostly nulls. For each method, you would have to write a separate query that would insert/update the appropriate table. With SQL Server, you can make a view which combines all these tables and abstracts away any joins:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
SELECT Super.ID, Super.A, Super.B, 
Sub1.C, Sub1.D, Sub1.E, 
Sub2.F, Sub2.G, Sub2.H, Sub2.I, 
Sub3.J
FROM Supertype_table as Super
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subtype1_table as Sub1 on Super.ID = Sub1.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subtype2_table as Sub2 on Super.ID = Sub2.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subtype3_table as Sub3 on Super.ID = Sub3.ID
```

So then you could just write something like:

```
SELECT ID, A, B, J
FROM MyView
WHERE J is not null
```

**EDIT : For OP's comment**

In order to ensure that each ID is in one and only one table, you need some kind of identifier on the supertype table. So if you had a column called TypeID, you would create the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SubtypeofSuperID](@ID int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @TypeID int;

    SELECT @TypeID = TypeID 
    FROM Supertype_table
    WHERE ID = @ID

  RETURN @TypeID 
END
```

Then, using that, you can create a check on each of the subtype tables:

```
ALTER TABLE Subtype1_table CONSTRAINT [CK_CorrectSubtype1]
CHECK ( [dbo].[SubtypeofSuperID]([ID]) = 1 )
ALTER TABLE Subtype2_table CONSTRAINT [CK_CorrectSubtype2]
CHECK ( [dbo].[SubtypeofSuperID]([ID]) = 2 )
ALTER TABLE Subtype3_table CONSTRAINT [CK_CorrectSubtype3]
CHECK ( [dbo].[SubtypeofSuperID]([ID]) = 3 )
```

Comment: I was thinking something like this initially, but there's one problem I had with it.  It was possible to have multiple subtype tables all point to the same Supertype row.  How do ensure that exactly one Supertype row applies to one and only one subtype table (and row within that table).

Comment: e.g. if I wanted disjoint subtypes, I would want to use a column in the Supertype to act as a subtype discriminator.  Is the enforcing on insert based on logical checks on my end? Or can the DB be setup to disallow such inserts automatically?

Comment: You'll have to make an explicit check one way or the other. I use the function + check method and it works for me. I would also make sure to do the check in your client code so the user gets a nice error message if they try to do something they're not supposed to. For me, the DB checks are the last line of defense.

Comment: Why do you need the function? You can do it with DRI

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways...

First of all, Jason's answer hits one of them -- breaking your design out into multiple tables -- and that can be a pretty good approach for most things.  (a.k.a. a more 'normalized' approach)

Alternatives...

1) You could have a string of name-value pairs in the last field.  For example:

```
ID   Method   DateTimeStart   DateTimeEnd   ValueString
1    1        2012-01-01...   2012-01-01... C:value,D:value,E:value
2    2        2012-01-01...   2012-01-01... F:value,G:value,H:value,I:value
```

So this might be handy in cases where you can't plan for value types ahead of time.  For example, maybe you need to be able to decide on the fly to start recording 'W' values for method 1, and it's not feasible to do a structural mod like you'd have to do in a more normalized design.

This is the common approach our E-sign Form developers use.  You can imagine a web form, such as "department leave request" that someone would fill out and route electronically for approval.  And then along comes a client who wants them to build a "purchase order" web form, that will have different fields & values that have to be recorded.  Rather than create a brand-new table for this (or add columns to existing tables, etc.), they use the name-value-pair model to store all forms data, no matter which form it is, in the same table.

2) You can use table triggers to enforce integrity, if you don't trust the person/process running inserts on your single big table.  For example, a before update trigger could check the method number, and then modify the data the person or process was attempting to insert by nullifying any inappropriate data values.

FWIW